# Copy a file from local machine to remote machine using WMI

Tags: c#, copy, wmi

I've tried figuring out how to copy a file from the local machine my program is running on onto a remote machine using C# and WMI (Without having to set up a share on the remote machine), but with no luck.

The source file could be on the local computer the program is running from or on share, but I do not want to have to set up a share on the destination machine.

Does anyone know how I could do this?

Comment: WMI has nothing to do with transfering files...

Comment: Ok, so I can't copy from the local machine. But it should be possible to tell the remote machine to copy a file from a share onto its harddrive through WMI?

Comment: Why do you think so? Where do you got that idea?

Comment: [link](http://www.google.no/#hl=no&q=copy+file+wmi&oq=copy+file+wmi&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=1486779l1488787l1l15l11l1l1l0l1l214l1284l1.7.1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=d402acc9aa124027&biw=1920&bih=951) Google.

Comment: Looks like you are right. I am sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I bashed my head on this until I found [Frank White's WMI method of using CMD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8884728/wmi-remote-process-to-copy-file/12149366#12149366) to create a way of doing this. As long as your account can access a shared folder (UNC, FTP, http, etc.) the workaround works:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11948096/1569434